# CGRect Frame Issue

Tags: uiview, core-animation, frame, cgrect

I keep getting a reoccurring issue while testing on iOS 7, I cannot figure out if its a BETA bug that has not been properly addressed or if its my code, or still if its a configuration problem.

I am trying to animate a UIView,

In my .h i have defined it like this

```
IBOutlet UIView *MainView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *MainView;
```

And in my .m this is the code. Its not a connection issue as the opacity (alpha) animation works just fine.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.3 animations:^{
    [settingView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    MainView.alpha = 0.3;
    MainView.frame = CGRectMake(-160.0f, -40.0f, ScreenSize.size.width, ScreenSize.size.height);        
}];
```

Any thoughts? Thanks a million!

Comment: From that code it seems very unlikely that it would be a iOS 7 bug (in which case I couldn't answer you because it's under NDA). Still, did you bother testing on iOS 6 to see for yourself if it could be a bug?

Comment: What is the frame before and after the animation?

Comment: Also, rethink some of those variable names. `settingsView` seems to be a controller since you are accessing its view. `ScreenSize` seems to be a rect since you are accessing its size. Just for clarity

Comment: Do your views have constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Abizern who suggested it maybe constrained. Turning off constraints works and another way around it was defining the components programatically in the .m